# Autoscaling mysql on ec2

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, master-slave

I need autoscaling of mysql-slave on ec2 can anybody guide me how to do that and how to transfer the load on newly added instance

Answer (score 1):

i would use opscode's chef.  you can create "roles" in chef, such as a slave_server role.  make the role set up a new server and install mysql (check out the opscode provided cookbooks for mysql to do the first parts).  Then what you want to do is write your own recipe to grab a copy of your slave db (perhaps grabbing a recent snapshot of the ebs volume of one of your other slave servers) and use that to create a new ebs volume on your new server.  Then its just a matter of making your recipe configure the server as a slave and get slaving going so it catches up to master.